# Facebook login javascript opens hundreds of Oauth access_token dialogs

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk

Ok.

As the title says my Facebook login javascript opens 100s Oauth access_token dialogs.

After i have logged in it just explodes with dialogs with access_token requests that popup.

But they dont remain they closes at once but i have to click on close 50 times or so to get them to stop reappearing.

This is strange behaviour....

See for yourself here:

[Test site](http://lucyseven.com/imp/prvk.php)

I get no errors in console.log so i have no idea on what might be causing this.

Any help will be rewarded with cheese and wine. ;)

Thanx

Comment: does not do that on my chrome windows. only one dialog open. time to update your browser.

Comment: yeah.. same here.. it only opens once in my `firefox` too...

Comment: Ok. But my browsers are up to date... 
I get this: [video](http://lucyseven.com/imp/FB.swf) 
So strange